# I'm making a warlock main villain

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design

If I make a warlock villain, would giving them PC features be unbalancing, for example, pacts and invocations

AC 11
HP 115
Str 10
Dex 14
Con 12
Int 14
Wis 16
Cha 20
CR 12

Resistance to damage from spells

My party is currently 6th level and I was figuring that by level 10 they should be able to take her on as well as her 4 Acolyte minions, which are using just the standard stat block from the monster manual

Comment: I think you've got a few questions in here that need to be parsed out and asked individually. Are you mostly wanting to know if you can create a NPC/Villain based off of a PC build? Or are you asking if your changes to the Archmage keep it at it's current CR?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Some of us are voting to close this question as unclear right now because there appear to be multiple issues you're trying to address, and we generally prefer to keep individual questions focused on specific issues. If you want to split this question into A) *"Am I allowed to use Player Character features when designing NPC creatures?"*, B) *"Would adding [this list of features] to the Archmage upset their balance?"*, as individual questions, we might be able to give them the attention they deserve.

Comment: Alternatively, if you manage to gain enough Rep to join chat (minimum required is 20), you could come ask this in our [General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), we would likely be more able to assist with your questions, along with any follow-up questions you might have, in a more personalized manner.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it to the more basic question I had in mind

Comment: Excellent! But we will definitely need the full stat block of your build and what CR you want it to be.

Comment: That's a good start, but I think it's missing information. I thought you said this was going to be based off of a warlock build? Are you doing the archmage conversion or are you building a standard PC Warlock?

Comment: I was going to just build a standard pc warlock, but my friend told me to use the template instead, so I was converting the archmage from having wizard stats to haviong warlock stats, as well as fiddling around with the spell list. Then he told me I cant include the warlock features since its not an actual pc, and thats where Im getting stuck.

Comment: You can [see this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58083/if-i-design-a-pc-for-use-as-an-npc-how-much-xp-should-he-give-when-killed) to cover using a PC build as NPC.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, it looks like I will try my original idea and just make some minor tweaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94269/discussion-between-nautarch-and-asiryft).