# How should XP be awarded when facing enemies with class levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, experience-points

A lot of games I've been in have had either enemies with player levels or straight up PvP. How should XP be awarded when facing enemies like that? Should you attempt to calculate the CR of the enemies based on the DMG tables or is there a guideline on how XP should be awarded based on the class levels?

Comment: Possible dupe: [If I design a PC for use as an NPC, how much XP should he give when killed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58083)

Comment: Actually, lulling it over, I do think it's a duplicate. If there's anything that doesn't answer, obviously do point it out to me (and everyone else for that matter).

Comment: I think the biggest thing that doesn't answer (and I'll add it in a comment over there too) is how to calculate the CR when the measurements are all over the table. Maybe I could make a question asking about a specific example...

Comment: Yup, that's usually done best with a specific example. Consider using the [tag:homebrew-review] and [tag:cr-calculation] tags, and their specific guidance.

Comment: Or you could add a bounty to get a better answer.

Comment: Tried to phrase a specific example into a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/172266/how-should-i-convert-this-characters-level-and-stats-into-a-cr)